# NERDTree-go does not leave cursor in the NERDTree

Tags: plugin-nerdtree

[NERDTree.txt](https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree/blob/master/doc/NERDTree.txt) says:

```
go.......Open selected file, but leave cursor in the NERDTree......|NERDTree-go|
         Open selected bookmark dir in current NERDTree
```

But when I typo `go` in a NERDTree buffer, selected file is opened in the current window, same as `o`.
I expect the file is opened in background buffer, is it right?

I tried to:

- Disable all other plugins.
- Remove .vimrc.

I use:

- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- vim 8.0
- NERDTree 6.7.7 via vim 8 pack

Answer (score 0):

Try `gs` (or `gi`) and then try `go`.

This is used to preview the file before opening and accomplishes what you are trying to do. `go` also does not work for me. But you can also simply map it, if necessary.